# How to estimate student's level according to score and time spend

Tags: machine-learning

I have some data that contains students answer, score, and time spent in many exams.

How to estimate each students level according to this data?

Sample data:

```
student ID, topic ID, score, time spend

  sid1    ,   tid1  ,  10  , 5s

  sid1    ,   tid2  ,  4   , 15s

  sid1    ,   tid3  ,  3   , 25s

  sid1    ,   tid4  ,  10  , 5s

  sid2    ,   tid1  ,  11  , 15s

  sid2    ,   tid2  ,  6   , 11s

  sid2    ,   tid3  ,  7   , 24s

  sid2    ,   tid4  ,  0   , 53s
```

Comment: Please share more information... Also it's a bad idea to judge a student's performance by the time spent..

Comment: @Aditya, then only score can be used?

Comment: how are you planning to derive the target variable? is it like if the score is above 20 as good and 10-20 avg and 0-10 poor? if you derive a variable from score(nothing but converting numeric variable to categorical) then how can you use that variable modelling? as @Aditya said, you cannot directly use it but try checking the correlation between target and time spent if you find some significance then you can think of including that variable. Generally based on business knowledge we reject some features from modeling. So think of any other factors which you think might influence the target var

Comment: Kind of decision tree  will now gauge a student's performance...

Answer (score 1):

I think there will be different approaches, and different results, to this problem.

The first which comes to my mind is simple:

1. evaluate the difficulty of each topic, by the average of the time spent by the students on it;
2. use the evaluations at point 1) to weight the time spent by the students on the topics;
3. calculate the average weighted time spent on all the topics;
4. a) you can rank the students based on the average weighted times, or

   b) you can plot an histogram of the average weighted times, and choose some proper tresholds to classify the students